# Change theme of my github pages, and pages are empty

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm new to `Github pages` and `Jekyll`, I follow the steps about how to build Github pages, and then succeed. When I changing the theme in `Settings` and refresh, it shows nothing in main page.

I don't override `_layouts` or anything else. Because it says Github support the theme so I would think I should do nothing to support the new theme, just like the default theme `Minima`.

So I wonder, does it just go like this or I missing something? Thanks for any idea :)

Comment: link the github page and repository -

Comment: @DenisTsoi https://github.com/Mioke/mioke.github.io  , I changed back the theme in `_config.yml` to default `minima`

Comment: In Github repo go to Settings/GitHub Pages and copy the Jekyll build failure messages in the question

Comment: @marcanuy Build success

Comment: @marcanuy I changed the theme now. mioke.github.io   I remove the line in  index.md `layout: home`

Comment: And it works ;)

Comment: I just wonder, theme `minima' support `layout: home`, but the theme I using now don't support it. why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Jekyll theme has a different set of layouts.

The default theme comes with four layouts:

1. default
2. home
3. page
4. post

While other layouts can have the same ones or a different set of layouts, in this case the other theme you chose only has one layout, that honors the *minimal* section of its name (jekyll-theme-minimal):

1. default

The default installation comes with few examples using different layouts, if you change to the *jekyll-theme-minimal* you only have one layout available (unless you add more by yourself).

Comment: Thx, I got it, I should take a look at the theme repo.

Comment: See these two blog posts: https://surfacedetail.blogspot.com/2019/04/github-pages-and-jekyll-themes.html and http://www.natalyakosenko.com/2017-12-23-how-to-switch-jekyll-theme-on-github-pages-site