# GitHub Pages are suddenly blank

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I had no issues for long time with GitHub Page and all worked like a charm. Suddenly for some unknown reasons the page shows blank content.

Any help on the below? What has been changed that has caused this issue?

Github Repo : https://github.com/Purus/purus.github.io

GitHub Page : https://purus.github.io

I have standard content in Gemfile.

Comment: Are you getting any build failure messages? https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-jekyll-build-error-messages/#viewing-jekyll-build-failure-messages-in-your-repository

Comment: No. I have not got build failure notifications. I get them only if I make any syntax error. But in this case, there no such errors.

Comment: One other thing to check that comes to mind. I see commits about removing the CNAME file -- In the repo Settings -> GitHub Pages -> Custom Domain have you cleared that value and clicked Save?

Comment: Yes, its now removed already. You can see that redirects not happening as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the theme to `jekyll-theme-leap-day` which only has a `default` layout, so you need to change all your posts where you specify `layout: page` or `layout: post` to `layout: default`.

You can also set this automatically using jekyll scopes **after removing the `layout` in each post** and applying the same process to `pages`:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "default"
```

Related answer: [Change theme of my github pages, and pages are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967184/1165509)

Comment: If you have noticed I have already commented that theme you mentioned. no worries.. Now I have moved to using Hugo instead of Jekyll.. Hugo is more friendly and provides more options.

Comment: Easy of Use for a beginner like me .. :)